# Google + sign in with laravel

Tags: api, laravel-4, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I have been struggling a lot for G+ sign-in with laravel, I have downloaded the php-sdk using composer. I am also using JavaScript to sign-in, once the once the user signs in I redirect him to a route from JavaScript to `/gLogin?email=abc@gmail.com&name=John Doe` where I have following code.

```
$user_profile['email']=Input::get('email');
    $user_profile['name']=Input::get('name');

    $user_id=DB::table('users') -> where('dyp_user_email', $user_profile['email'])-> pluck('dyp_user_id');
    if($user_id)
    {
    $user_to_be_logged_in=new user();
    $user_to_be_logged_in = User::find($user_id);
    }
    else
    {
    $password=$token = str_random(16);
    $hash=Hash::make($password);
    $user_to_be_logged_in = user::create(array('dyp_user_type' => 'IN', 'dyp_name' => $user_profile['name'], 'dyp_user_email' => $user_profile['email'], 'dyp_mobile_number' => '','dyp_password'=> $hash,'dyp_user_status' => 'VF'));

    $data = array('name' => $user_to_be_logged_in -> dyp_name, 'password' => $password);
        Mail::send('emails.fbUserRegistration', $data, function($message) use ($user_to_be_logged_in) {
        $message -> to($user_to_be_logged_in->dyp_user_email, $user_to_be_logged_in->dyp_name) -> subject('Thanks for registering with dreamyourproperty.com');
    });

    }

    Auth::login($user_to_be_logged_in);
```

There is a serious security problem here, that I am not able to validate the user's session. 
I someone manually hits the url `/gLoin?email=abc@gmail.com&name=xyz` then also my code will authenticate him.

In comparison to G+ signin FB login was pretty simple.Can someone provide me guidance, I am seriously stuck with this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way you want to handle this is `/gLogin?access_token=xyz` where `xyz` is the users Google+ access_token. Make a request to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) authenticated with that access token. That way you have server side validation the current user is validated for the specific Google+ profile.

Comment: Thanks, it gave me a right direction and I am now clear with the way Google has implemented it.